# Jquery UI tabs: can't get the correct tab order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've been trying to get the order of JqueryUI tabs with the following code in the addTab function of the example given here:[jqueryUI tab demo](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation)

```
function addTab() {
  var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
    id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
    li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
    tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

  tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
  tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
   //code for finding the tab order
   var tab_order = [];
   $("#tabs > ul > li > a").each(function(i){          
        tab_order[i]= this.id.substr(6);
   });
   alert(tab_order);


  tabCounter++;
}
```

the first time a new tab is added, the the order of tabs alerted is 1,3 and not 1,2 which should be the case. here's the fiddle:[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jackhammer94/v04ses9x/)

Comment: Do you want the ID of the tab, or the tab content div you insert?

Comment: I want the ID of the tab

Comment: All relevant code should be included in the question. Consider replacing your jsFiddle link with a [stack snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)